# How to incorporate criteria in Where method?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to ask about the WHERE condition in my search command. I'm calling web service (API) during searching and I want to put WHERE statement in my code but there's an error.

```
    private async Task CallApi(string searchText = null)     
    {           
        long lastUpdatedTime = 0;                           
        long.TryParse(AppSettings.ComplaintLastUpdatedTick, out lastUpdatedTime);

        var currentTick = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;            
        var time = new TimeSpan(currentTick - lastUpdatedTime);


        if (time.TotalSeconds > 1)          {
            int staffFk = Convert.ToInt32(StaffId);
            var result = await mDataProvider.GetComplaintList(lastUpdatedTime, mCts.Token, staffFk);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {

                // Save last updated time
                AppSettings.ComplaintLastUpdatedTick = result.Data.Updated.ToString();

                // Store data into database
                if ((result.Data.Items != null) &&
                    (result.Data.Items.Count > 0))
                {

                    var datas = new List<Complaint>(result.Data.Items);

                    **if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                        {
                            datas = datas.Where(i => i.Description.Contains(searchText)
                                                 && (i.SupervisorId.Equals(StaffId))
                                                || (i.ProblemTypeName.Contains(searchText)));
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            datas = datas.Where(i => i.SupervisorId.Equals(StaffId));
                        }**

                    Datas = new ObservableCollection<Complaint>(datas);
                }
            }
            else if (result.HasError)
            {
                await mPageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error", result.ErrInfo.Message, "OK");
            }           
     }      
}
```

Both assignments of `datas` in the `if ... else` causes `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ECS.Features.Complaints.Complaint>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ECS.Features.Complaints.Complaint>'.  An explicit conversions exists (are you missing a cast?)` compilation errors:

[image: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ECS.Features.Complaints.Complaint>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ECS.Features.Complaints.Complaint>'. An explicit conversions exists (are you missing a cast?)" compiler error]

I don't know how to use the WHERE condition there. Please help me. Thank you in advance for your concern.

Comment: `datas` is a `List<Complaint>` but you try to reassign it to `IEnumerable<Complaint>` with the `Where` statement. Add a `ToList()` after the Where to maintain type, Otherwise you could just declare datas as `IEnumerable<Complaint>`

Comment: **there's an error.** is not very specific, if you could provide the error code, or what it says, it would help a lot.

Comment: I've uploaded the error for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: I added the error text to the question because, compared to a screenshot, that makes it easier/possible for search engines, accessibility tools, and future readers to consume.  Not to mention one would think that copying and pasting text would be less work than cropping and uploading an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datas` is a `List<Complaint>` but you try to reassign it to `IEnumerable<Complaint>` with the `Where` statement. Add a `ToList()` after the Where to maintain type,

Or you could just declare `datas` as `IEnumerable<Complaint>`

```
IEnumerable<Complaint> datas = new List<Complaint>(result.Data.Items);
```

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. The code works. But my list view become empty by default. When I enter the searchText, the related data appear. How to appear all the data by default?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that `datas` is defined as being a `List<Complaint>`, and the return type of `datas.Where(...)` is an IEnumerable/IQueryable.

You could do:

```
datas = datas.Where(i => i.SupervisorId.Equals(StaffId)).ToList();
```

Complete code:

```
private async Task CallApi(string searchText = null)     
    {           
        long lastUpdatedTime = 0;                           
        long.TryParse(AppSettings.ComplaintLastUpdatedTick, out lastUpdatedTime);

        var currentTick = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;            
        var time = new TimeSpan(currentTick - lastUpdatedTime);


        if (time.TotalSeconds > 1)          {
            int staffFk = Convert.ToInt32(StaffId);
            var result = await mDataProvider.GetComplaintList(lastUpdatedTime, mCts.Token, staffFk);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {

                // Save last updated time
                AppSettings.ComplaintLastUpdatedTick = result.Data.Updated.ToString();

                // Store data into database
                if ((result.Data.Items != null) &&
                    (result.Data.Items.Count > 0))
                {

                    var datas = new List<Complaint>(result.Data.Items);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                        {
                            datas = datas.Where(i => i.Description.Contains(searchText)
                                                 && (i.SupervisorId.Equals(StaffId))
                                                || (i.ProblemTypeName.Contains(searchText))).ToList();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            datas = datas.Where(i => i.SupervisorId.Equals(StaffId)).ToList();
                        }

                    Datas = new ObservableCollection<Complaint>(datas);
                }
            }
            else if (result.HasError)
            {
                await mPageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error", result.ErrInfo.Message, "OK");
            }           
     }      
}
```

You will then also have an error on the next line, `Datas = new ObservableCollection` becasue `Datas` is not defined, and if you meant `datas`, again, it will not be the List<> that you initially defined.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. The code works. But my list view become empty by default. When I enter the searchText, the related data appear. How to appear all the data by default?